# java reference variable not working as expected when used with unary increment(decrement) operations

Tags: java, reference

In the code bellow I excpected the Output to be `true, 0`. However the output is `true, 1`. Since cnt is a reference variable to the Value of the Key-Value Pair with Key 3. I thought the operation `cnt--`; would change the value where the reference variable is pointing at. However the experimental code shown bellow doesn't seem to change the value in the HashMap.
I'm confused because if `get` method returns a copy of the instance, then the `equals` operation should return false. Yet it is returning true so it is just returning a reference to an instance. Then why is that unary decrement operation not working?

Thank you in advance. Any feedback to the clarity of the question is welcome.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Equals {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int n : nums1) {
      map.put(n, map.getOrDefault(n, 0) + 1);
    }

    Integer cnt = map.getOrDefault(3, 0);
    Integer cnt2 = map.get(3);

    System.out.println(cnt.equals(cnt2));
    cnt--;
    System.out.println(cnt2);

  }
}
```

Comment: The variable `cnt` is an [`Integer`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html). `Integer`s are immutable. When `cnt--` is executed, the JVM uses [autounboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to transform the `Integer` in an `int` and decrements that `int`. IntelliJ, for example, warns that the value of `cnt--` is never used. So in essence, we are not changing the original `Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--` operation is an operation on a **variable**.  In the case of an `Integer` variable, it updates the variable to a new reference value ... representing the number - 1.  It is equivalent to

```
// cnt--;
cnt = Integer.valueOf(cnt.intValue() - 1);
```

The `--` operator cannot change the value held within the existing `Integer` object.  `Integer` objects are immutable!

So ... when you increment the variable, it doesn't affect the value in the `HashMap` entry.

Comment: Thank you I have just realized the `equals` method is overrided in the Wrapper class. There for the `equals` method is returning the comparison between two values.